# how to redirect url when use httpd on centos 7

Tags: apache, react-router

I use react-routers in my project. I use webpack to package my javascript code. But when I run my project on linux server that is centos 7, it occurs some problem. I tried http://116.xx.xx.xx, it works well. But when I tried http://116.xx.xx.xx/login, it can not find the URL because it tried to find var/www/html/myproject/login/index.html rather than use react-router. By the way, the project is run on port 80, I use httpd to serve it. So I guess it's my httpd.conf has something wrong. I want to know how to redirect /login to index.html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can use Apache module (mod_alias ):

File: httpd.conf

Redirect Domain:

```
Redirect / http://www.new-domain.com/
```

or

```
Redirect permanent / http://www.new-domain.com/
```

Redirect Page:

```
Redirect /web-page.html http://www.new-domain.com/destination-web-page.html
```

Note:

- Redirect directives take precedence over Alias and ScriptAlias
  directives.
- Other "Redirect" options include: temp (error 302) default -
  temporary redirect status, seeother (error 303) resource has been
  replaced and gone (error 410) resource has been permanently removed.

Example httpd.conf with virtual hosts for multiple domains which all redirect:

```html
<VirtualHost XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX>

ServerName directtolinux.com

ServerAlias www.directtolinux.com

ServerAlias direct-to-linux.com

ServerAlias www.direct-to-linux.com

ServerAlias digitalpenguins.com

ServerAlias www.digitalpenguins.com

Redirect permanent / http://www.yolinux.com/

</VirtualHost>
```